# Dropzone and upload to multiple folders

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello, I'm looking for a way to upload files to folders.

I have a dropzone on the website where I can put all files and then upload it. But what I need is to choose **which file to which folder.**

I want to add 3rd button (select option) to which folder upload it. Probably using the `onChange` event.

Any idea how to do it only for that only one file ?

Example:

body.png   START    CANCEL    FOLDER (images) - when i press start, it will upload to images folder

styles.css START    CANCEL    FOLDER (css) - when i press start, it will upload to css folder

**Upload script:**

```
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

**Dropzone script:**

```
<script>
      var previewNode = document.querySelector("#template");
      previewNode.id = "";
      var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
      previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);

      var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, { // Make the whole body a dropzone
        url: "upload.php", // Set the url
        thumbnailWidth: 80,
        thumbnailHeight: 80,
        parallelUploads: 20,
        previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
        autoQueue: false, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
        previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
        clickable: ".fileinput-button" // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
      });

      myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
        // Hookup the start button
        file.previewElement.querySelector(".start").onclick = function() { myDropzone.enqueueFile(file); };
      });

      // Update the total progress bar
      myDropzone.on("totaluploadprogress", function(progress) {
        document.querySelector("#total-progress .progress-bar").style.width = progress + "%";
      });

      myDropzone.on("sending", function(file) {
        // Show the total progress bar when upload starts
        document.querySelector("#total-progress").style.opacity = "1";
        // And disable the start button
        file.previewElement.querySelector(".start").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
      });

      // Hide the total progress bar when nothing's uploading anymore
      myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function(progress) {
        document.querySelector("#total-progress").style.opacity = "0";
      });

      // Setup the buttons for all transfers
      // The "add files" button doesn't need to be setup because the config
      // `clickable` has already been specified.
      document.querySelector("#actions .start").onclick = function() {
        myDropzone.enqueueFiles(myDropzone.getFilesWithStatus(Dropzone.ADDED));
      };
      document.querySelector("#actions .cancel").onclick = function() {
        myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
      };
    </script>
```

**AND the body construct:**

```
<body>

  <div class="container" id="container">
    <h1>Dropzone.js</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="actions" class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-7">
        <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            <span>Add files...</span>
        </span>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
            <span>Start upload</span>
        </button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
            <span>Cancel upload</span>
        </button>

      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-5">
        <!-- The global file processing state -->
        <span class="fileupload-process">
          <div id="total-progress" class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="table table-striped" class="files" id="previews">

      <div id="template" class="file-row">
        <!-- This is used as the file preview template -->
        <div>
            <span class="preview"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="name" data-dz-name></p>
            <strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></strong>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="size" data-dz-size></p>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary start">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
              <span>Start</span>
          </button>
          <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-warning cancel">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
              <span>Cancel</span>
          </button>
          <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-danger delete">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
            <span>Delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

(Proof of concept only, needs much refinement, validation and security measures.)

This sets up a dropzone that requires the "Submit all files" button to be clicked before upload starts. When a file is added to the dropzone a select list with folder names is loaded along with the file preview. Select a folder name for each upload item, then click the submit button. The files are uploaded and each one gets directed into the folder that is designated by it's corresponding folder select list.

form.html

```
<button id="submit-all">Submit all files</button>
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"></form>

<script>

Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

  // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
  autoProcessQueue: false,

  init: function() {
    var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all"),
        myDropzone = this; // closure

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files
    });

    this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
        var select = document.createElement('select');
        select.setAttribute('name', 'folder[' + file.name + ']');

        var option;
        option = document.createElement('option');
        option.innerHTML = 'images';
        select.appendChild(option);

        option = document.createElement('option');
        option.innerHTML = 'css';
        select.appendChild(option);

        document.forms[0].appendChild(select);
    });
  }
};

</script>
```

upload.php

```
<?php

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fp = ( isset($_POST['folder'][$filename]) )? $_POST['folder'][$filename]: '';
    $folder = ( 'images' == $fp || 'css' == $fp )? $fp: 'upload';

    move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
        dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' . $folder . '/' . $filename
    );
}
else { echo 'error: no file'; }

?>
```

A side note: it's apparent that dropzone causes an XHR action for each file that is uploaded. Therefore every element in the form, including every select list, gets appended to the formData object of the XHR for every file uploaded, resulting in redundancy.